# How to make a sonarcloud project with two codebases in one repo

Tags: c#, angular, sonarqube, monorepo, sonarcloud

I have a backend .net project and a frontend angular project. Both are in the same repo but are different codebases, mainly because github doesnt support monorepos and we are trying not to have a lot of repositories for one project all scattered.

I made a build.yml script that is good and builds and scans both backend and frontend project. But in my SonarCloud project it only shows it has one codebase, when scanned sometimes its only C# and sometimes Javascript, Typescript, HTML, CSS.

Is there a way that sonarcloud scans two codebases in one repository and when on sonarcloud I can see that my project has C#, Javascript, Typescript, Html and scss (not just one codebase) ?

I tried making a build.yml file that builds both backend and frontend and scans them both but that didnt work...